# Remapping Caps Lock to ctrl+b

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, tmux, keyboard-layout, gnome-terminal

I recently moved to Linux from OSx and in there I had mapped <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. This was mostly done because of tmux.

How can I do this in Ubuntu 14?

There is a very comprehensive answer here how to remap keys:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys

But this doesn't cover a key combination like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. It only covers remaping a single key to another key.

Comment: There's a very [comprehensive answer to this over](http://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys) at AskUbuntu.

Comment: This doesnt cover pressing 2 buttons at once, i.e. Ctrl + b